# Disable comments field based on flag field in Account object

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I do want to disable a Account_Comment custom field based on Account_Flag field in Account object.How to achieve it thru VF page and Apex class

Answer (score 0):

Call a method on the onclick of the flag and make the rendered of the comment field to false.